# How to display the event in calendar using codeiginter?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I have display the calendar and the following code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<link href='https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/
bootstrap.min.css'>
<link href='https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.print.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar/3.9.0/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar/3.9.0/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min
.js'></script>
<script>

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month'
      },
      defaultDate: new Date(),
      navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: true,
      droppable: true,  // allow "more" link when too many events
      dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {

        $("#successModal").modal("show");
        $("#eventDate").val(date.format());

      },
       events: <?php echo json_encode($myArray); ?>   });

  });

</script>
<style>

  body {
    margin: 40px 10px;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  #calendar {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id='calendar'></div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="successModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="successModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Apply Leave</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form action="#" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="eventtitle">Event Title:</label>
      <input type="text" name="eventTitle" class="form-control" id="eventTitle" required="" value="Leave">
<!--      <input type="color" name="eventColor" class="form-control" id="eventColor" required="">-->
      <input type="hidden" name="eventDate" class="form-control" id="eventDate">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Apply Leave</button>
  </form>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is view page code.In this page when click the date it pop up and i click apply leave button the data is store in the database.but it doesn't shows in front page of calendar when it saved into database.

My controller code

```
public function index()
    {
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]) == "submit" && isset($_POST["eventTitle"]) != "")
      {
        $da=array(
                  'title' => $this->input->post('eventTitle'),
                  'event_date'=> $this->input->post('eventDate'),
                );

         $sql = $this->db->insert('events',$da);
            if ($sql) {
                echo "New event added successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
                }
    }

    $sql['row'] = $this->db->query("SELECT title, event_date as start, backgroundColor FROM events")->row_array();

if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
    while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
        $myArray[] = $row;
    }

} 
else 
{
    echo "0 results";
}
        $this->load->view('Leave');
    }
```

It displays only "0' value and some errors

Comment: What kind of errors?

Comment: it shows warning only like this

Comment: Warning: include(/opt/lampp/htdocs/Task/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Task/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 268

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/opt/lampp/htdocs/Task/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Task/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 268

Comment: and i know why it is coming too

Comment: how to change the while loop in codeiginter

Comment: [google](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=calendar+codeigniter+example), [other source](https://medium.com/@kshitij206/calendar-library-in-codeigniter-961af6f1bbb6) etc.

Answer (score 0):

> Change your query into this code **Hope this helps !**

```
$sql = $this->db->select('title, event_date as start, backgroundColor')->get('events');
if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {   
    foreach($sql->row_array() as $row){
    $myArray[] = $row;    
    }
```

Comment: in front view page code in events what i have to write

Comment: events: <?php echo json_encode($myArray); ?>   here

Comment: but it display echo '0' only

Comment: check my sample code for your reference  https://github.com/eboominathan/Basic-Crud-in-Full-Calendar-Using-Codeigniter-3.0.3

Comment: here is different